# PHP: Demonstrate Headers Already Sent

Tags: php, http-headers, runtime-error

Note: I am *not* trying to solve the `headers already sent` problem. I am trying to *create* one!

I thought I understood what causes this error, and I am trying to demonstrate it to some students. Here is a sample script:

```
Hello

<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    print 'This space for rent …';

    setcookie('test',12);
    header('Testing');
?>
```

As you see, I am trying my best to send output before setting a header, either indirectly by setting a cookie, or directly using the `header()` function.

As weird as the question sounds, how can I get this error to appear?

Comment: If output buffering is on in the php.ini it won't throw the error as output is captured and sent at the end. This is sort of like the "lazy man's" way to prevent these errors instead of actually fixing the scripts causing them. You can create the error by turning this off or ending output buffering before the output with something like `ob_end_clean()` (then output, then header)..

Comment: I didn’t realise that it was possible to do that in `php.ini`. Your suggestion did the trick. Could you turn you comment into an answer so that I can accept this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If output buffering is on in the php.ini it won't throw the error as output is captured and sent at the end. This is sort of like the "lazy man's" way to prevent these errors instead of actually fixing the scripts causing them. You can create the error by turning this off or ending output buffering before the output with something like ob_end_clean() (then output, then header)

Comment: As I commented above, I didn’t realise that you can do this in `php.ini`. I have also found that you can add this to the `.htaccess` file: `php_value output_buffering …`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To create this error, just use header() function in any place after the page header.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>.....</title>
</head>
<?php
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Make sure that your php.ini is set to display these errors too.